# App crashes when trying to take a second picture

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

I can take a picture and display it in a new layout. But when I go back to my previous layout and try to take a new picture, my application crashes saying 'camera stopped'

I am a beginner with android. Can anyone help me?

EDIT: My app crashed because I had an onclick in my XML

This is my crash report:

```
12-18 10:06:36.000 16690-16690/groep4.multec.integration.ehb.com.camera E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-18 10:06:36.000 16690-16690/groep4.multec.integration.ehb.com.camera E/AndroidRuntime: Process: groep4.multec.integration.ehb.com.camera, PID: 16690
12-18 10:06:36.000 16690-16690/groep4.multec.integration.ehb.com.camera E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method sendMessage(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.widget.ImageButton with id 'buttonFoto'
12-18 10:06:36.000 16690-16690/groep4.multec.integration.ehb.com.camera E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(View.java:4485)
12-18 10:06:36.000 16690-16690/groep4.multec.integration.ehb.com.camera E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4449)
12-18 10:06:36.000 16690-16690/groep4.multec.integration.ehb.com.camera E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
12-18 10:06:36.000 16690-16690/groep4.multec.integration.ehb.com.camera E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21153)
12-18 10:06:36.000 16690-16690/groep4.multec.integration.ehb.com.camera E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
12-18 10:06:36.000 16690-16690/groep4.multec.integration.ehb.com.camera E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-18 10:06:36.000 16690-16690/groep4.multec.integration.ehb.com.camera E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
12-18 10:06:36.000 16690-16690/groep4.multec.integration.ehb.com.camera E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
12-18 10:06:36.000 16690-16690/groep4.multec.integration.ehb.com.camera E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-18 10:06:36.000 16690-16690/groep4.multec.integration.ehb.com.camera E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
12-18 10:06:36.000 16690-16690/groep4.multec.integration.ehb.com.camera E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Here is my code:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageButton btnTakePhoto;
    ImageView imgTakenPhoto;
    private static final int CAM_REQUEST = 1313;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnTakePhoto = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonFoto);
        imgTakenPhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.genomenFoto);


    btnTakePhoto.setOnClickListener(new btnTakePhotoClicker());
}
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == CAM_REQUEST){
            setContentView(R.layout.share);
            Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            imgTakenPhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.genomenFoto);
            imgTakenPhoto.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
        }
    }

    class btnTakePhotoClicker implements Button.OnClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAM_REQUEST);
        }
    }
    //Share layout -- back button - Go back to main layout
    public void ibBackToPhotograph(View v) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Comment: please post your crash report

Comment: Do you have any click in your xml for buttonFoto?

Comment: Yes, thank you!
I removed the onclick and the application no longer crashes!
After going back to my main layout, the buttonFoto (btnTakePhoto) no longer works and doesn't open the camera, any idea why?

Comment: now you need to write a simple click listener for btnTakePhoto , it will work

Comment: Where exacty do I add it? I added it at my method 'ibBackToPhotograph' but it didn't do anything
(btnTakePhoto.setOnClickListener(new btnTakePhotoClicker());)

Thanks for all the help :)

Comment: can you able to show a toast on that ?

Comment: Sorry I don't know how..

Comment: i mean u need to show a Toast inside your onclick listener of your button?

Comment: The button is supposed to re-open the camera intent. It works the first time, but if I decide to take a new picture and go back to the main layout the button doesn't respond.

Comment: Never mind.. I made the same mistake as before. I had to add:
 btnTakePhoto = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonFoto);
to my method. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your class ibBackToPhotograph function

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
```

replace your old view with new view . 
I you want to interact with new UI you need to declare each widgets again as below

```
public void ibBackToPhotograph(View v) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnTakePhoto = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonFoto);
    imgTakenPhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.genomenFoto);
    btnTakePhoto.setOnClickListener(new btnTakePhotoClicker());
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how I can easily display the previously taken picture in that layout? (which was displayed in the share layout)

Comment: calling setContentView() multiple times on an Activity  will overwrite the layout, and replace it with a new one.

Comment: when your camera  activity exits, your onActivityResult() method will be called with the given requestCode and you can access your UI elements from there.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == CAM_REQUEST){
        setContentView(R.layout.share);
        Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        //imgTakenPhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.genomenFoto);
        imgTakenPhoto.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
    }
```

and

```
class btnTakePhotoClicker implements ImageButton.OnClickListener
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it didn't help